# jQuery syntax for adding var into selector

Tags: jquery, syntax, selector, var

I have 2 problems.

1) I'm new to jQuery, so I can't figure out the correct syntax for adding vars into multiple selectors - not sure if that makes sense.

So here we have a simple, two column, connected, sortable lists. Works just fine without trying to add the var roomID into it. What's the correct syntax for this?

```
$( ("#sortable1-"+roomID), ("#sortable2-"+roomID) ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    dropOnEmpty: true,
}).disableSelection();
```

**HTML**

```
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="40%">
          <p>
          <ul id="sortable1-1" class="connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default"><?php echo $item; ?></li>
          </ul>
          </p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <center>
          <br />
          <p>
            <a href="#" class="add-all">&lt; Add All</a>
          </p>
          <br />
          <p>
            <a href="#" class="remove-all">Remove All &gt;</a>
          </p>
          <p>
            <br />
            <a href="#" class="reset">Reset</a>
          </p>
        </center>
      </td>
      <td width="40%">
        <p>
        <ul id="sortable2-1" class="connectedSortable">
          <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
        </ul>
        </p>
      </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

2) With above sortable list in mind, is there an easy way to add all items from one list to the other? Similar to a "Add All" or "Remove All" button ?

Thanks!

Comment: #1 should be `$("#sortable1-"+roomID,"#sortable2-"+roomID)`

Comment: Then I can't imagine why this isn't working... adding HTML...

Comment: Try reproducing the problem in a jsFiddle.

Comment: One problem per question. Since it seems you want to create **one**  selector, you have to pass **one** string, not two: `$("#sortable1-" + roomID + ", #sortable2-" + roomID)`

Comment: I will limit my questions in the future.

That worked, Felix. Thanks!